# My integral doesn't evaluate

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

i'm doing something called Sommerfeld expansion i got somehelp online source i will show after code.
Sommerfeld expansion to integrate Fermi-Dirac equation to find total number of particles N for energy i define to be x.

The problem is sometimes either of my integral eq1 or eq2 dosn't work! i need them to be evaluated. can someone help please!
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := 1/(Exp[(x - u)/(k*t)] + 1);

h[x] = -D[f[x], x]; 

g1 = Normal[Series[g[x], {x, u, 7}]]; 
g2 = Normal[Series[g[x], {x, u, 10}]]; 
g3 = g2 - g1; 
G1 = Simplify[g1*h[x] /. {x -> u + k*t*y}]; 
G2 = Simplify[g3*h[x] /. {x -> u + k*t*y}]; 


eq1 = Simplify[k*t*Integrate[G1, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     Assumptions -> {k > 0, t > 0}]]

eq2 = Simplify[k*t*Integrate[G2, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     Assumptions -> {k > 0, t > 0}]]

f1 = PowerExpand[eq1 + eq2]
```

**I just did the same! but no result!? 
the result should be given as in last lines here**
[image]

Comment: You're taking the Series expansion of `g`, which is undefined in your code.  Is this intended, or is `g` actually supposed to be `f`?

Comment: it's defined both g 1 and g 2 , f is something else in the beginning

Comment: i edited and added some source code picture look at it

Comment: I'm not sure why Mathematica is able to compute the first integral in one case but not another, but here's one thing you can do to ensure that it computes the integral. In the definition of `eq1`, do `Integrate[#, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {k > 0, t > 0}] & /@ Expand@G1` instead of `Integrate[G1, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     Assumptions -> {k > 0, t > 0}]`.

Comment: that's smart solved the problem

Comment: also is faster in computing.
please put it as answer for this site so i check it's all right.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the integral isn't computing. Here's a fix:

Use

```
Integrate[#, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {k > 0, t > 0}] & /@ Expand@G1
(* g[u]/(k t)+1/6 k π^2 t (g^′′)[u]+7/360 k^3 π^4 t^3 (g^(4))[u]+(31 k^5 π^6 t^5 (g^(6))[u])/15120 *)
```

This expands the function first, then integrates each term separately.

---

It also doesn't help to `Expand` the integrand first, which is strange, since I figured that the symbolic pre-processing that *Mathematica* does would include using the linearity of the integral.  (Although, I guess *Mathematica* can't assume this since there are some integrands for which the integral of each term diverges where the integral of the sum of the integrands does.)